# Why is nested function not changing the variable of main function

Tags: python, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

```
def findAllPaths(vertices, Alist, source, dest):
    result = []
    path = []
    visited = []

    def find_path(Alist, source, dest, path, visited):
        path.append(source)
        visited.append(source)

        if source == dest:
            result.append(path)
        else:
            for i in Alist[source]:
                if i not in visited:
                    find_path(Alist, i, dest, path, visited)
        visited.pop()
        path.pop()
    find_path(Alist, source, dest, [] ,[])

    return result


INPUT:
    vertices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    AList = {1: [3, 4], 2: [3], 3: [6], 4: [6, 7], 5: [4, 6], 6: [2], 7: [5]}
    source = 1
    destination = 2
OUTPUT:
    [[], [], []]
```

I want to get all the paths from a source to destination in graph. The nested function is giving paths but not changing the variable out of it.

Comment: You may have meant to write: `result.append(path[:])`. This is because although your code appends `path`, two instructions later you have `path.pop()` which then modifies that `list`.

Comment: Also note that `path = [] ;  visited = []` is redundant. You can delete those two lines.

Comment: How is this question related to digital signature algorithm to be tagged with [tag:dsa]? Please don't add irrelevant tags!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code a little bit, but the main problem is that you need to use copy when saving path, because if you don't that all other changes of path also change when path is in result, cause it is the same object actually.

```
def findAllPaths(vertices, Alist, source, dest):
    result = []
    path = []
    visited = []

    def find_path(Alist, source, dest):
        nonlocal result
        path.append(source)
        visited.append(source)

        if source == dest:
            result.append(path.copy())
        else:
            for i in Alist[source]:
                if i not in visited:
                    find_path(Alist, i, dest)

        visited.pop()
        path.pop()

    find_path(Alist, source, dest)

    return result


vertices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
AList = {1: [3, 4], 2: [3], 3: [6], 4: [6, 7], 5: [4, 6], 6: [2], 7: [5]}
source = 1
destination = 2

print(findAllPaths(vertices, AList, source, destination))
```